# Apache - how to use a rewrite rule per vhost?

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, virtualhost

I have set up a vHost as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

DirectoryIndex index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/www/

<Directory />
    Options -FollowSymLinks -Includes -Indexes  -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/example.com/www/>
    <LimitExcept GET POST>
         deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
    Options -FollowSymLinks -Includes -Indexes  -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to add a rewrite rule as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So that i can add a subdomain to my website, but ensure that all traffic to `example.com` or `anything.example.com` besides `dev.example.com` is directed to `www.example.com`.

Where would i place this rule to make it effective?

I have tried every which way, including placing it in httpd.conf but it seems to either break the vhost config or have no effect.

Any ideas and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is your default server - IE `VirtualHost` may be a `NameVirtualHost` - then apache will only pass requests for example.com and `www.example.com` to the rewrite rule if its within the given `VirtualHost` block. If you add `anything.example.com` to ServerAlias then you might find it works in that context, but just for `anything.example.com`

To make the rule effective you need to place it in the default `VirtualHost` block, that is the `VirtualHost` that appears when you access the server by IP address, not name. On a lot of Apache installs this is handled by a default handler (welcome to Apache style page). Removing that `VirtualHost` can make this one the default, as can moving this virtualhost further up the config file.